# How to document a defunct function properly?

Tags: r, rd

**What I have read**

I have read [this SO question and related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099128/are-there-best-recommended-practices-to-follow-when-renaming-functions-in-a-new) but I am still a bit at loss of how to document a `defunct` function properly in my package.

**What I have tried**

- I replaced the code of my `defunct`fucntion by a call of `.Defunct("<pointer to a function to be used instead>", "<my package name>")`
- I deleted the `.Rd` file containing the old documentation of my function
- I created a `mypackage-defunct.Rd` file with an alias pointing to my now `defunct` function name
- In `mypackage-defunct.Rd` I created an `\usage` entry for my old function and replaced the function arguments by `\dots` (as I do not see the need to keep track about the old arguments. I followed a bit what is done in [base-defunct](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/base/man/base-defunct.Rd))

**What I have got**

When running  `RCMD CHECK` I get the following `WARNING`:

> **checking Rd \usage sections ...** WARNING
>   Undocumented arguments in documentation object 'mypackage-defunct'
>     '...'
>
> Functions with \usage entries need to have the appropriate \alias
>   entries, and all their arguments documented.
>   The \usage entries must correspond to syntactically valid R code.
>   See chapter 'Writing R documentation files' in the 'Writing R
>   Extensions' manual.

**What I would like to have**

How do i get rid of the warning? Do I need to document arguments from `defunct` functions? Bonus question: What is the recommended way for a defunct function. Should I remove all arguments and replace them by `...`? Looking at `base-defunct`, I see a mix of functions with proper argument names, `.` and  `...`arguments and empty argument lists. What is the "correct" way?

Comment: I'm also wondering the same thing. Coincidentally it's only 5 days after your question. Let's see if I get responses on twitter https://twitter.com/daattali/status/929561336337403904

Comment: How did you finally handle it?

Comment: It's been a while now, but IIRC, I replaced the arguments in the defunct by `...`